# Move from one to the other tabItem by using actionButton() in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

Im trying to add an `actionButton()` in the fist tabItem that when pressed will move to the second tabItem named `widgets`. I cannot understand what am I doing wrong.

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="inTabset",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  tabItems(
    # First tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            "dashboard",
            actionButton("nextt","Next") 
                         
    ),
    
    # Second tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
            "widgets"
    )
  )
  observeEvent(input$nextt, {
    updateTabItems(session, "inTabset",selected = "dashboard")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you added the `tabItems` in the server instead of inside `dashboardBody`. Additionally, to switch from `dashboard` to `widgets` you have to do `selected="widgets"` in `updateTabItems` and finally your server should have an argument `session`:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "inTabset",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        actionButton("nextt", "Next")
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "widgets"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$nextt, {
    updateTabItems(session, "inTabset", selected = "widgets")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: u could also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74603743/move-from-one-menuitem-to-another-usung-actionbutton-when-the-name-of-it-can-b