# Move from one menuItem to another usung actionButton() when the name of it can be changed in a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the `shiny` app below in which I would like to set the name of the second `menuItem()` by typing in the `textInput()` of the first `menuItem()`. And then move to it by clicking an `actionButton()`. Also why the `textOutput()` I use is dispalyed under the icon and not next it like the first one?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
   
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE,
    sidebarMenu(
      id="inTabset",
      menuItem("Workspace", tabName = "workspace", icon = icon("upload")),
      
      menuItemOutput("tab2")
      
      
      
      
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "workspace",
              fluidRow(
              
                         
                        
                           
                           textInput("name", "", value = "Process model", placeholder = NULL),
                           actionButton("nextt","Next", icon("paper-plane") 
                                        )

                         
                       )
                       
                )
                
      ),
      
     
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Process model",
        
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$tab2 <- renderMenu({
    menuItem(text = input$name, tabName = "Process model", icon = icon("diagram-project"))  
  })
  observeEvent(input$nextt, {
    updateTabItems(session, "inTabset", selected = "Process model")
  })
  
  
  
  output$tabtitle <- renderText({
    if (input$name == "") {
      "Process model"
    } else {
      paste(input$name)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nextt, {
    updateTabItems(session, "inTabset", selected = "Process model")
  })
  
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically create and name a `menuItem` you could use `renderMenu` and `menuItemOutput`.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "inTabset",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItemOutput("tab2")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        textInput("name", "Create a name for your process", value = "", placeholder = NULL),
        actionButton("nextt", "Next")
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "widgets"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$nextt, {
    updateTabItems(session, "inTabset", selected = "widgets")
  })
  
  output$tab2 <- renderMenu({
    menuItem(text = input$name, tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))  
  })
  
  output$tabtitle <- renderText({
    if (input$name == "") {
      "Name of process"
    } else {
      paste(input$name)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$nextt, {
    updateTabItems(session, "inTabset", selected = "widgets")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you stefan your code works but I edited and now something seems to not work can you check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607277/navigate-through-tabitems-usings-actionbutton I made a new Q